# WordPress image resize on hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a [wordpress website](http://rafsk.co.uk/) and I'd like to add some features that my current theme doesn't offer. I'd like the 3 images in the "Pages" section to reduce in size or switch to a different image (same content, smaller resolution) so as to appear smaller then you hover over it. I've managed to accomplish this with a custom HTML page, adding ID's to the images and then adding a version of this to my style.css for each image

```
#techbutton {
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background: url("http://rafsk.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Logo21-e1445171629993.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
#techbutton:hover {
  background: url("http://rafsk.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Logo2-hover-e1445296643552.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
#techbutton span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
}
```

After uploading the custom HTML to my server I realised that instead of just overriding the homepage of rafsk.co.uk it also overrode the homepages of all my subdomains.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a css transform, that would be the easiest way, and you can apply it to all three with a class instead of an id (which should only be used once per page):

So first give the same class to all of the images (meaning to the actual image tag, like `<img class="imageclass" src="blah.png" />`), and use this in your css:

```
.imageclass {
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  transform: scale(1,1);
}
.imageclass:hover {
  transform: scale(0.9,0.9);
}
```

You could then add a css transition effect if you want it to be smoother:

```
.imageclass {
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  transform: scale(1,1);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.imageclass:hover {
  transform: scale(0.9,0.9);
}
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/f9teea7L/

---

**ALTERNATIVE OPTION #1:**
If you can't edit the HTML and can only get an image into the div through the background, you could try adding a background-size property like this. Be aware though that it won't work in IE 8 or lower:

```
#techbutton {
  display: block;
  background-image: url('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/deadliestfiction/images/d/d5/2138464123_1360632315.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140513035922');
  background-size: 100%,100%;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  transform: scale(1,1);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
#techbutton:hover {
  transform: scale(0.9,0.9);
}
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/azx962a9/

---

**ALTERNATIVE OPTION #2:**
I've looked at your site though and if I'm understanding what you want to do, it seems to me that simply adding this to your css should work...:

```
.service-icon {
  transform: scale(1,1);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.service-icon:hover {
  transform: scale(0.9,0.9);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a great idea, the only issue is that I can't actually edit the HTML myself because it's based on a WordPress theme. So I'm unable to add classes to the images.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to see this.  You could try going up the CSS cascade instead of adding a class. So you'd use `#techbutton img` and `#techbutton img:hover`

Comment: Or if there's some reason to have to use the image as a background, you could try the `background-size` css property... I'll edit the answer above with a possible solution.